# Proof that $\sin(x) > x/2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I need to prove that $\sin(x) > \frac{x}{2}$ if  $0<x<\pi/2$

I've started working with the derivative, but if it's possible, I'd rather something simpler than that.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin{x}<\frac{x}{2}$ if $0<x<\frac{pi}{2}$?

I think you misspelled "sin" and you want a lower bound on $x$ or this isn't true...for example, $sin{\frac{-3\pi}{2}}=1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I´m sorry, I meant sin, I keep writing it the spanish way... And I definitely meant $sin(x)>x/2$... Must miss the symbol while typing it.

Comment: You mean when $0\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$. I find derivative easiest, one can use more basic but more complicated geometry.

Comment: $\sin{x}$ is strictly concave on $x\in \left[0,\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right],$ therefore, $\sin{x}>\frac{2}{\pi}x>\frac{1}{2}x.$

Comment: Ok, then I´ll keep working with the derivate, but I have problems when I consider cos(x) after $\pi/6$, beacuse it reaches 1/2, and that is the derivate of x/2... any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's rewrite the desired inequality as

$${\theta\over2}\lt\sin\theta\quad\text{for }0\lt\theta\le{\pi\over2}$$

To prove this, draw the portion of the unit circle in the first quadrant, draw a typical angle $\theta$ from the origin $O$ to a point $P=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, and let $Q=(1,0)$.  The wedge of the circle for this angle has area $\theta/2$.  It consists of two pieces:  the triangle $\triangle OPQ$, of area ${1\over2}\sin\theta$, and a lens-shaped piece outside the triangle.

Here's the key point to convince yourself of:  If you reflect the lens-shaped region across the line $PQ$, it *stays inside the triangle* $\triangle OPQ$, and therefore has smaller area.  The upshot is that the area of the wedge is less than twice the area of the triangle, which is exactly what we want.

**Added later**:  Here's a second proof based on the same picture.

In addition to the points $P=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $Q=(1,0)$, let $R=(1,y)$ be the point of intersection of the two tangents to the circle at $P$ and $Q$.

Now the length of the circular arc from $Q$ to $P$ is, by definition, $\theta$ (when the angle is measured in *radians*).  But this length is less than the sum of the lengths $QR$ and $PR$.  By symmetry, those two lengths are the same.  Thus, since the length of $PR$ is obviously just $y$, we have $\theta\lt2y$.  But $R$ clearly lies closer to the $x$-axis than $P$, hence $y\lt\sin\theta$.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @LunaSage, you're welcome.  I added a second proof just for fun.

Comment: Both the proofs are almost falling in category of "proof without words" if a diagram is given. Its bit tricky compared to usual proof of $\sin \theta < \theta$. Really very clever. +1

Answer (score 13):

Since $\sin(x)$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(x)
&\ge\sin(0)+(x-0)\frac{\sin(\pi/2)-\sin(0)}{\pi/2-0}\\
&=\frac{2x}{\pi}\\
&\ge\frac x2
\end{align}
$$

$\hspace{8mm}$[image]

Comment: Which theorem are you using?

Comment: Or that´s part of the definition?

Comment: @LunaSage: I am using the fact that $\sin(x)$ is concave and that for a concave function $$f(x)\ge f(a)+(x-a)\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can only accept one answer, I think, but this is really useful. +1

Comment: @LunaSage: Glad it was helpful. Yes, you can upvote or downvote each of the answers, but [you can only accept one](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin x > x-\frac{x^3}{6}$ for $x>0$, we can show that $x-\frac{x^3}{6}>x/2$ with your condition. That is, $$x>\frac{x^3}{3}\\1>\frac{x^2}{3}\\ \text{At the max of x, show } 1>\pi^2/12$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw the  line trough $(\cos x,\sin x)$ and tangent to the unit circle.  This line slopes down (at an angle $x-\tfrac{\pi}{2}$) and intersects the line $x=1$ in the point $(1, \tan \tfrac{x}{2})$.  So $$ \sin x>\tan\frac{x}{2}>\frac{x}{2}.$$