# Proving that this integral is divergent

Tags: integration, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{x^2}$$

I have thought a lot but the absolute value just messes every way I try.

Comment: Hint: What happens for small $x$?

Comment: The trouble is near $0$, where you could use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674153/proof-that-sinx-x-2).

Comment: For small $x$ the Maclaurin expansion of $\sin x \approx x$ therefore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{|\sin x|}{x^2}:\frac{1}{x}\right)=1\ne 0\;\wedge\;\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}\text{ divergent }$$ $$\Rightarrow \int_0^1\frac{|\sin x|}{x^2}\text{ divergent }\Rightarrow \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin x|}{x^2}\text{ divergent.}$$